# tkinter multiple buttons using lambda function

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to create multiple buttons in tkinter library (with numbers as text), using for loop. And i want to print the text of each button every time i click one. Like a calculator. But the problem is that it prints only the last line in the loop.

```
win=tk.Tk()
def butt(x):
    print(x)
for i in range(1,4):
    bt=tk.Button(win,text=i,command=lambda: butt(i));bt.pack()
win.mainloop()
```

One solution of this that i found is to write lambda i=i : ... but i dont understand what this is.
Thank you for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expression here returns the method that prints the `i` value.

```
import tkinter as tk

win=tk.Tk()

def get_print_method(x):
    def print_i():
        print(x)
    return print_i

for i in range(1,4):

    bt=tk.Button(win, text=i, command=get_print_method(i))
    bt.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Lambda in your case is an equivalent of the get_print_method function.

Answer (score 0):

This a well-known behavior in Python for `lambda`

> This happens because *i* is not local to the lambdas, but is defined in the outer scope, and it is accessed when the lambda is called — not when it is defined

[Python FAQ on lambdas](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

Their solution, is to give `lambda` a default parameter

```py
import tkinter as tk
win=tk.Tk()
def butt(x):
    print(x)
for i in range(1,4):
    bt=tk.Button(win,text=i,command=lambda j=i: butt(j))
    bt.pack()

#i = 'This is now a string'

win.mainloop()
```